# Updating screen after a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, text, grid, javafx

The purpose of this program is to collect surveys from users. Once the user fills out the 3 text fields, he has to click Submit. If all 3 text fields are filled out, a text will show right below the submit button. If any of the 3 fields is blank and the user clicks submit, he will get an error (text).

So, the problem is that the "Success" text and the "Error" text overlap. For example, if I am not able to submit the survey the first time, but get it right the second time, my screen ends up looking like this:

[image]

I am using a GridPane for the layout of this scene.

You can see the source code below.

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FileWriter stream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(stream);

        Text error = new Text("Error. Make sure all fields are filled out.");
        Text success = new Text("Survey submitted. Thank you!");

        //Save the survey only if all text fields are filled out.
        if (!fullName.getText().contentEquals("") && !email.getText().contentEquals("") && !comment.getText().contentEquals("")) {
              out.write("Name: " + fullName.getText());
              out.write("\tEmail: " + email.getText());
              out.write("\tComment: " + comment.getText());
              out.close();
              success.setFont(new Font("Ariel", 15));
              success.setFill(Color.GREEN);
              grid2.add(success, 0, 13,3,4);
         } else {
              error.setFont(new Font("Ariel", 15));
              error.setFill(Color.RED);
              grid2.add(error, 0, 13,3,4);

         }

     } catch (IOException ex) {
         System.out.println("ERROR SAVING FILE.");
     }
     }
});
grid2.add(submitButton, 0, 11);
```

Comment: You can just use the same Text and set the string content, is also better for memory consumption...

Comment: I tried using the same string and just .setText depending on the case, but it did not work either unfortunately.

Comment: And if you try to set the visibility of the Text field? Sorry, for keep with this kind of go horse approach...

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing .setVisible(false), depending on the case, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Just found an example that uses Label instead of Text and I think is exactly what you are trying to do: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/text-field.htm

Comment: Sadly it does not work with a Label either. What is wrong with my source code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44637/discussion-between-ghostderfel-and-user2915567)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We find the solution on our chat, the problem was that he was adding the Text Fields on the action handle when the correct way was to update the content on the action handle and have the Text or Label field created with the other elements on the screen :)